# Print all propabilitys for a XML Element in Python 2-7

Tags: python, xml

I try to programming in Python a Script, which is generate automaticly a XML File whith some information in there.

So i am stuck on a Point. I have 6 subelements. The text of a subelement can be a 0 or a 1.
I want print all possibility for the 6 Elements.

What I have:

```
listTCPFlag["fin","syn","rst","psh","ack","urg"]
lustTCPFlagAnswer = [0,1]

listProtocol = ['TCP','UDP','ICMP']
top = Element('Test')
ipHeader = SubElement(top, 'IpHeader')    
ipProtocol = SubElement(ipHeader,'protocol')

    for x in range(len(listProtocol)):
        ipProtocol.text = str(listProtocol[x])

        if(ipProtocol.txt == "TCP"):
             tcpHeader = SubElement(top, "tcpHeader")
             tcpPort = SubElement(tcpHeader,"destPort")
             tcpFlag = SubElement(tcpHeader, "flag")

             tcpFlagFin = SubElement(tcpFlag, "fin")
             tcpFlagSyn = SubElement(tcpFlag, "syn")
             tcpFlagRst = SubElement(tcpFlag, "rst")
             tcpFlagPsh = SubElement(tcpFlag, "psh")
             tcpFlagAck = SubElement(tcpFlag, "ack")
             tcpFlagUrg = SubElement(tcpFlag, "urg")


             # I tried to implement this in a for loop:

             for z in range(len(listTCPFlag)):
                 for u in range(len(listTCPFlagAnswer)):

                     if(listTCPFlag[z] == "fin"):
                           tcpFlagFin.text = str(listTCPFlagAnswer[u])

                     # ...
```

After careful consideration and testing, I found that the loop is wrong.. And now I am in a thoughts gap and don't know how I can fix this problem.. My output should be like:

Example:

1. `<root>`
   `<element_1> 0 </element_1>`
   `<element_2> 0 </element_2>`
   `<element_3> 0 </element_3>`
   `<element_4> 0 </element_4>`
   `<element_5> 0 </element_5>`
   `<element_6> 0 </element_6>`
   `</root>`
2. `<root>`
   `<element_1> 0 </element_1>`
   `<element_2> 0 </element_2>`
   `<element_3> 0 </element_3>`
   `<element_4> 0 </element_4>`
   `<element_5> 0 </element_5>`
   `<element_6> 1 </element_6>`
   `</root>`
3. `<root>`
   `<element_1> 0 </element_1>`
   `<element_2> 0 </element_2>`
   `<element_3> 0 </element_3>`
   `<element_4> 0 </element_4>`
   `<element_5> 1 </element_5>`
   `<element_6> 0 </element_6>`
   `</root>`
4. `<root>`
   `<element_1> 0 </element_1>`
   `<element_2> 0 </element_2>`
   `<element_3> 0 </element_3>`
   `<element_4> 1 </element_4>`
   `<element_5> 0 </element_5>`
   `<element_6> 0 </element_6>`
   `</root>`
5. `....`
6. (eventually)

`<root>`
   `<element_1> 1 </element_1>`
   `<element_2> 1 </element_2>`
   `<element_3> 1 </element_3>`
   `<element_4> 1 </element_4>`
   `<element_5> 1 </element_5>`
   `<element_6> 1 </element_6>`
`</root>`

After that i try it with a "add_binary_nums(x,y)" function. Like this: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/challenges/1/python-challenges-1-exercise-31.php

For my Opinion I prefere a for-loop which can handle with that. But I have no Idea how it could be build. How can i do it in a simply way in Python 2 and in a For - loop ?

Comment: Why is the second group in your example `010000` instead of `000001`? Do you want them in a randomaized order?

Comment: Typing error, sry... I edited it, i don't want, them in a randomaized order... :s

Comment: Why did you delete your question after I [edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52398436/18771)? (And then took all my edits and copy-pasted them into a new question?)

Comment: No reason? Well, if there is no reason, then please take my advice and don't do that anymore with future questions. Other people editing your posts is a completely normal thing on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Tomalak sry, i didnt see you question. I delete the question, because i did not get a answer... The reason is not, because you editing the post. If you want, you can edit it again... The reason was, to hope that i get a Answer on the new better question.

Comment: That's even worse. Don't delete and re-post your question because you have not received an answer and want to push it to the front page again. That's rude. It was *an hour old*, what did you expect? Sometimes it takes a day or more until someone finds the time to answer your question.

Comment: You are right... I am sorry....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most concise way to do this that I can think of would be to write a `for` loop that iterates over all the numbers from `0` to `63` (`2^6 - 1`) in binary as this would go from `000000` to `111111`. Then split each number into individual digits and put each digit within one of your `<element>` tags.

Here's an example:

```
all_possibilities = []

for n in range(2**6):
    binary = format(n, '06b')
    tcp_flag_elements = []
    for i in range(len(binary)):
        subelement = SubElement(tcpFlag, listTCPFlag[i])
        subelement.text = binary[i]
        tcp_flag_elements.append(subelement)
    all_possibilities.append(tcp_flag_elements)
```

This will leave you with the list `all_possibilities` containing 64 lists, one for each of the possible configurations of your subelements.

Comment: Should that `06b` be `0:b`?

Comment: @Chillie I think that's the notation of `str.format`, but here this `format` is a bit more direct way to convert `n` to binary. Specifically, the `6` is important so that all the binary numbers have the same length and the `0` says to fill the space with `0`, so that, for example, `2` comes out as `000010` instead of just `10`.